# how to get compileSdkVersion equal or higer than the options shown

Tags: android-studio, admob

I'm making an app with ads in it with AdMob: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=he.

In order to that I need a "compileSdkVersion 28 or higher", so when I tried to change it by doing:
right-click on "app" > open module settings > compile SDK version, I was shown that the maximum option is: compile SDK version 27, and not 28 the minimum requirements for Google AdMob

[image]

also here is my build.gradle(Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.minesweeperyannai"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'//Google AdMob dependency
}
```

Also, I checked on their website and found out that I cant use lower versions than 19.4.0 or 18.1.0 (I didn't understand which one is the minimum but both of them didn't work).

This is the error I get when I try to use one of those versions:

> error: failed linking references.

And I know my code is good because I've tried using the version: "play-services-ads 17.1.1" and it worked but only with test ads and not real ads, so to sum up I would like to know how to get Compile Sdk Version 28 or higher in order to show ads on my app.

Comment: download the sdk version 28 from SDK manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu showing you the versions that you already installed it

so to get version 28 or 29 you need to install it

The first option is to change it from build.gradle file for example

```
android
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        .....
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
   ....
}
```

Or from SDK Manager select show package details and install Android SDK Platform 28 or 29 then select it from the Compile Sdk Version menu

[image]